# How to hide toolbar in react navigation

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I want to know how to hide toolbar which is being added by default after implementation of `react-navigation` https://reactnavigation.org/

I have two screens - Launcher screen where I do not want a toolbar and 2nd screen where it is OK to have toolbar.

**index.android.js**

```
/**
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import EnableNotificationScreen from "./EnableNotification";

class SplashScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    console.disableYellowBox = true;
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require("./img/talk_people.png")} />
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 22, textAlign: "center" }}>
          Never forget to stay in touch with the people that matter to you.
        </Text>
        <View style={{ width: 240, marginTop: 30 }}>
          <Button
            title="CONTINUE"
            color="#FE434C"
            onPress={() => navigate("EnableNotification")}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 16,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column"
  }
});

const ScheduledApp = StackNavigator(
  {
    Splash: { screen: SplashScreen },
    EnableNotification: { screen: EnableNotificationScreen }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Splash"
  }
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent("Scheduled", () => ScheduledApp);
```

**EnableNotification.js**

```
/**
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default class EnableNotificationScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return <View><Text>Enable Notification</Text></View>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to hide toolbar you can try below code:

```
const ScheduledApp = StackNavigator(
  {
    Splash: { screen: SplashScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
          header: {
            visible: false
          }
      }
    }
 },
    EnableNotification: { screen: EnableNotificationScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: {
            visible: true
          }
        } 
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Splash"
  }
);
```

Cheers :)

Comment: `Splash: { screen: SplashScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
      header: {
        visible: false
      }
    }` what syntax is this of ES6 ?

Comment: ```header: null```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44615628/2646756 for a working solution.

Comment: header: {visible: false} has been deprecated use navigationOptions:{headerShown: false} instead.

Answer (score 25):

```
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null ,
  };
```

this works for me

```
class SplashScreen extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null ,
  };

  render() {
    console.disableYellowBox = true;
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

All the answers I could find were from React navigation v4 for some reason, which doesn't work in v5. After spending some time on it I figured out a way to hide toolbar in v5. Here it is:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

...

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

....
//and inside render
render(){
    return (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeScreen}
                options={{
                  title: "Home",
                  headerShown: false,
                }}
              />
}
```

`headerShown: false,` this will do the trick

Answer (score 9):

To hide header for only one screen do this in `createStackNavigator` function:

```
const Navigation= createStackNavigator({
  Splash: {
    screen:SplashScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
     header:null        // this will do your task
   }
  },
  Dashboard:{screen:Dashboard}
}
);
```

To hide header(toolbar) for all screen of createStackNavigator
add

```
{
  headerMode:'none'
}
```

inside `createStackNavigator`. like this:

```
const Navigation= createStackNavigator({
  Splash: {
    screen:SplashScreen
  },
  Dashboard:{screen:Dashboard}
}
,{
  headerMode:'none'
}
);
```

Note : I am using `createStackNavigator` which may be `StackNavigator` for others. So if you are using `StackNavigator` do all this changes as i did in `createStackNavigator`

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who ended up here, I believe the most up-to-date answer for disabling the header for the entire app looks like this:

```
export const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Register: { screen: Register },
  Login: { screen: Login },
},{
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Register',
})
```

note that now it's `headerMode: 'none'`. I tried `header: null` to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Check release notes, it's `header: null`, not `header: { visible: false }`. It was a breaking change.

you can check on this link https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1275#issuecomment-297718049